# Understanding why list object has no attribute name?

Tags: arcpy

I have this script which gives me an attribute error and points out **line 8**.

The error says

> " 'list' object has no attribute 'name'"

Not sure what went wrong.

How do I fix this script to run?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/MyFolder"
fc = "airports.shp"
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
for field in fields:
    if fields.name == "NAME":
        for row in rows:
            print "Name = ({0}".format(row.getValue(field.name))
```

Comment: What is you tried if field.name == "NAME": in your code.

Comment: That worked like a charm!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @dvldgs05 please accept Keagan's answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

From the code provided, I tested the following:

Your if Statement is looking at "Fields" You want the if statement to look at the Field in the list of Fields.

Change:

```
if fields.name == "NAME":
```

to

```
if field.name == "NAME":
```